# Removing selected dataframes from a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r

If I have a list of dataframes, i.e.

lst comprises of dataframes named "aa0" "a0000" "a00a0a" "aababa00" "aaba" "000" "a00" "00000".....

Each of the dataframe consists of some rows and 3 columns. I want to remove those dataframes which have names containing all 0's. That is, the output will be,

lst will comprise of "aa0" "a0000" "a00a0a" "aababa00" "aaba" "a00"....

How can I do this? Thanks!

I see no reason for downvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing names that consist only of 0s can be done this way

```
lst<-c( "aa0" ,"a0000", "a00a0a" ,"aababa00" ,"aaba", "000" ,"a00" ,"00000",'1001')
lst[-grep('^[0]+',lst)]
```

Comment: Will this work even if the names contains numbers? Like "110" "000" "1111" "110100110" ?

Comment: Nope. So the names that are "good" might contain numbers and letters? And the names that are "bad" are strictly 0s?

Comment: Yes. I mean there are two different lists, one that contains names which are made up of numbers (including all 0's) and the other which contains names made up of letters. (including all 0's ). In both the cases, I want to remove those dataframes from the list whose name contains all 0's.

Comment: Then removing all 0s will be achieved with the above.

Comment: Go ahead and post a separate question for that, so that things are easily searchable for others. If the above answer suffices, please close the question.